# TFS annotate detect removal of code

Tags: tfs, annotate

This sounds like a simple thing to do, but I am not sure if it is possible ...

If I use TFS annotate, I can determine when each line of code was changed and the changeset where it was changed. This is great for determining when something was added or modified. But what about determining when something was removed?

Does the removal of code appear in an annotate? I don't think it does. If not, how can I detect when some code was removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the removal of code appear in an annotate?

I don't think so.

Which leaves taking diffs between specific versions, perhaps using divide and conquer to find the specific changeset.

Comment: Yeah - I have always done a divide and conquer ... until today when faced with a change that was made 3 years ago, and ~1000 changes inbetween. It got me thinking that there must be a better way! (or perhaps not)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible, annotation does not show code removal. You can open the History dialog for a File, Ctrl+Select 2 fairly separate changesets and then Compare those and see if the line was there or not. Keep increasing/decreasing the range of the changesets until you find it.